# Convert list of ASCII codes to string (byte array) in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of integer ASCII values that I need to transform into a string (binary) to use as the key for a crypto operation. (I am re-implementing java crypto code in python)

This works (assuming an 8-byte key):

```
key = struct.pack('BBBBBBBB', 17, 24, 121, 1, 12, 222, 34, 76)
```

However, I would prefer to not have the key length and unpack() parameter list hardcoded.

How might I implement this correctly, given an initial list of integers?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need a 'binary' string?

Comment: `222` isn't an ASCII value. Is it a typo, or are your bytes actually characters from some ASCII-based national code page?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I much prefer the [`array`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) module to the `struct` module for this kind of tasks (ones involving sequences of *homogeneous* values):

```
>>> import array
>>> array.array('B', [17, 24, 121, 1, 12, 222, 34, 76]).tostring()
'\x11\x18y\x01\x0c\xde"L'
```

no `len` call, no string manipulation needed, etc -- fast, simple, direct, why prefer any other approach?!

Comment: This makes the most sense to me, logically.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: the method `tostring()` is now deprecated since python 3.2. call `tobytes()` instead, which is a clearer name for what is actually happening.

Answer (score 58):

For Python 2.6 and later if you are dealing with bytes then a `bytearray` is the most obvious choice:

```
>>> str(bytearray([17, 24, 121, 1, 12, 222, 34, 76]))
'\x11\x18y\x01\x0c\xde"L'
```

To me this is even more direct than Alex Martelli's answer - still no string manipulation or `len` call but now you don't even need to import anything!

Comment: For those who are wondering, Alex Martelli's answer does seem to run faster, at least with my benchmarks in Python 2.7.7.  For 10,000 runs it's 12ms for his answer vs 18ms for this; these numbers are repeatable with little variation.  Granted it's not a huge gain, just when working with a lot of data.  That said, this answer is actually faster for me at 8ms: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12073686/353094

Comment: @leetNightshade That said in Python 3.4.1 x86 this method is the fastest according to my benchmarks.

Comment: `>>> str(bytearray([42]))
"bytearray(b'*')"
>>> import sys; sys.version
'3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:05:16) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)]'`

Answer (score 48):

This is reviving an old question, but in Python 3, you can just use `bytes` directly:

```
>>> bytes([17, 24, 121, 1, 12, 222, 34, 76])
b'\x11\x18y\x01\x0c\xde"L'
```

Comment: Excellent, clean and simple!

Comment: This is probably the "most correct" answer for python3

Comment: How to do the exact opposite? (bytes -> array)

Comment: @Tino: Bytes to list, you mean? You can simply use list(): list(b'spam') → [115, 112, 97, 109]

Answer (score 11):

```
struct.pack('B' * len(integers), *integers)
```

`*sequence` means "unpack sequence" - or rather, "when calling `f(..., *args ,...)`, let `args = sequence`".

Comment: Interesting; I should have realized that I could use multiplication on the string, but I did not know about the 'unpack sequence'.  Thank you!

Comment: good solution, also can use `'%dB' % len(integers)` or even `'{}B'.format(len(integers))`

Answer (score 7):

```
key = "".join( chr( val ) for val in myList )
```

Answer (score 1):

Shorter version of previous using `map()` function (works for python 2.7):

`"".join(map(chr, myList))`