# Convert a list of integers to a bytearray in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x, arrays

I'm brand new to Python (C is my main language), so this may be a super basic/naive question.

I have two lists of integers that I'm generating with the following Python code:

```
mainList = range(100)
random.shuffle(mainList)
list1 = mainList[:len(mainList)/2]
list2 = mainList[len(mainList)/2:]
```

Basically, I'm trying to send each of these lists (`list1` and `list2`) over a TCP connection, and I want to make sure that I'm only sending a 50-byte payload for each (each list contains 50 integers).

What would be the best way to do this? Would the `bytearray()` function be applicable here, at all?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470398/list-of-integers-into-string-byte-array-python

Comment: [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack)

Comment: You mean pack `int` to  one byte?

Comment: Thanks for the help, Ashwini! (and thank you for trying to help, luoluo--sorry I didn't see your question until now!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the following method. First use Python's [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html?highlight=struct.pack#format-characters) module to pack your list of integers into binary, using 4 bytes per integer. The `I` specifies the size required, so if your integers are only byte values, you could change this to `B`.

`zip` and `iter` are then used to grab 50 bytes at a time from the byte list. This would then mean you could make it any length you like:

```
import random
import struct

main_list = range(100)
random.shuffle(main_list)

# 'I' meaning unsigned int of 4 bytes
bytes = struct.pack("{}I".format(len(main_list)), *main_list)

for send_50 in zip(*[iter(bytes)]*50):
    print len(send_50)
```

Tested using Python 2.7

Comment: Is this a common idiom?  It took me a couple of minutes to figure out how it works, and I think I'd have been flummoxed if I came across it in code.

Comment: Fairly common, it is based on the `grouper` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes).

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't even know about those itertools recipes; you can learn something new about python very day.

Comment: Thanks, Martin! Your answer definitely gave me a nice primer to struct.pack()  and zip() + iter(),  before looking them up in the Py documentation. Also, your method is much more concise than I would've thought up! Can't wait to learn more as I go along with the language. Thanks again.