# Java/Python:Convert int to byte[] array

Tags: java, python

I am porting some Python code to Java, well, a lot is done but I got stuck on this function. It should convert an `int` to a `byte[]` array.

I know that the if-statement is like `? :`, but I need some help.

```
def adjustId(self, _id):
        _id = format(_id, 'x')
        zfiller = len(_id) if len(_id) % 2 == 0 else len(_id) + 1
        _id = _id.zfill(zfiller if zfiller > 6 else 6)
        # if len(_id) % 2:
        #     _id = "0" + _id
        return binascii.unhexlify(_id)
```

So my question: How do I convert this code into java?

Comment: Your input is not an int as far as I can see, can you please define what's inside?

Comment: `c ? x : y` is the so-called ternary conditional. The normal `if` is preferable: `if (c) { x; } else { y; }`

Comment: please look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470398/list-of-integers-into-string-byte-array-python

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @Polygnome well, how to write this in Java :/

Answer (score 0):

You must use Python module "struct" pack unpack for convert int->bytes
Then convert Python "bytes" type to a tuple of bytes