# How to convert between the byte format that looks like [8, 200, 1, 16] to the one that looks like b'\x08\xc8\x01\x10\xc8 in python

Tags: python, arrays, formatting

I'm not sure what this type of byte array format is called in python:
**Format A:**
`[8, 200, 1, 16, 200, 1, 24, 200, 1, 34, 21, 8, 1, 18, 17, 98, 97, 116, 116, 108, 101, 95, 116, 97]`
but I'd like to convert it into this format (the name of which I’m also unsure of):
**Format B:**
`b'\x08\xc8\x01\x10\xc8\x01\x18\xc8\x01"\x15\x08\x01\x12'`

I know how to get from Format B to Format A:
`import array
data =b'\x08\xc8\x01\x10\xc8'
print array.array('B', data))`

but I'm unsure of how to get from Format A to Format B, and because I also don't know the names of either format, the google results I've gotten have been sparse.

Comment: I've found the answer you're looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470398/list-of-integers-into-string-byte-array-python        array.array('B', data).tostring()

Answer (score 2):

Piece of cake in Python 3:

```
>>> L = [8, 200, 1, 16, 200, 1, 24, 200, 1, 34, 21, 8, 1, 18, 17, 98, 97, 116, 116, 108, 101, 95, 116, 97]
>>> bytes(L)
b'\x08\xc8\x01\x10\xc8\x01\x18\xc8\x01"\x15\x08\x01\x12\x11battle_ta'
```

If you're back on Python 2:

```
>>> L = [8, 200, 1, 16, 200, 1, 24, 200, 1, 34, 21, 8, 1, 18, 17, 98, 97, 116, 116, 108, 101, 95, 116, 97]
>>> str(bytearray(L))
'\x08\xc8\x01\x10\xc8\x01\x18\xc8\x01"\x15\x08\x01\x12\x11battle_ta'
```